# TaskListener vs custom listener

Tags: activiti

I have a TaskListener implemented. In notify's implementation:

```
public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
  delegateTask.getId();
  ....
  ....
}
```

I get valid value from getId().

On other hand,in process definition I have configured a custom listener as:

```
<activiti:taskListener event="create" expression="#{myCusomtListener.notify(task)}"></activiti:taskListener>
```

And its implementation is as:

```
public class MyCusomtListener{
  public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
       delegateTask.getId();
       ....
       ....
     }
}
```

But, in this case getId() returns null.

Why this difference in behaviour?
And is there a way to get task id in second case?

Comment: `expression` follows `${...}` type expression i guess

Comment: delegateTask is valid. But getId returns null.